# Repair flawed experiment design

Tags: experiment-design

I seem to have uncovered a methodological flaw in a published large study dataset that originally took about 30 years to collect and collate. The experiment had a sequence of stimuli in a globally unique randomized order — i.e. each interview was conducted in the same order, but the order was randomized once as part of the experiment design.

By analyzing the data, I have discovered that the first stimulus behaves differently from the rest: adjacent stimuli correlate pretty well (Absolute value of Pearson r between 0.3 and 0.85, with p-values far under 0.05); except for the first stimulus in the randomized order, which correlates with its neighbors far less (Pearson r at around -0.07, p ~ 1e-25).

Before writing these findings up and publishing them I would like to be able to suggest methods to still use the collected data for further analysis, which leads me to my question:

What strategies might be worth pursuing for extracting reliable conclusions from a dataset suffering from this type of sequential “burn-in” issues with the data collection method? Is there a good source I can read on handling data from flawed experimental design?

Comment: "each interview was conducted in the same order, but the order was randomized once as part of the experiment design." So, first a number of stimuli were defined, then they were randomized, and then the interviews were performed? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's it. As part of the equipment issued to the fieldworkers administering the experiment was the stimuli sequence; randomized to disentangly perceptually close stimuli from each other, but with a single order issued to all fieldworkers.

Comment: So, there is only one order. All results that you have come from the same randomized order. Sorry, your formulation suggested that there might be something else. Second question, then: what is the question you need to answer with this data? (differences between groups? between stimuli? both? correlations? predictions? longitudinal studies?)

Comment: The data was collected to investigate universal tendencies across different national populations in reactions to the stimuli; to see whether the reaction patterns decompose into discrete “building blocks”. I guess it's a question of correlations between stimuli.

Comment: I'm trying not to identify exactly which study it is, since I want to have a preliminary draft written up and at least shared with the originators of the study before I go all out public.

Comment: What about a time series approach? Fit some AR model and work on the residuals or include other predictors after that?